# VisualStudio installer not showing up

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio

I have installed VS2013 Professional, made an application and wanted to deploy it, but the problem is, "Visual Installer" doesn't seem to be there, and I don't want "ClickOnce".

One more thing is that the database info is in the app.config, how could I make it so that no one sees the db info?

Comment: by installer you mean MSI installer? If so, than you should know that vdproj project templates (the projects that allowed to create msi pacakges) are no longer supported, since VS 2012. You can use instead InstallShield limited edition (ISLE) for VS (google it for instructions) or learn WiX (Windows Installer Xml) which is another way for you create MSI packages via configurable xml files.

Comment: if you don't want click once just copy the EXE file from the bin\release folder.

Comment: @Roman They brought it back for 2013, but not built in. You have to install it [as an extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the info. Had no idea they resurrected it.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer to your second question on encrypting the app.config file is rather simple and easy to use:**

Protected Configuration Provider helps in encrypting the sections of configuration file in order to protect the sensitive information of the application. This will results in making the application difficult for attacker to fetch sensitive information. .NET framework provides two ways of protected configuration provider:

1. RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider: This uses RSACryptoServiceProviderto encrypt the configuration sections
2. DPAPIProtectedConfigurationProvider: This uses Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) to encrypt configuration section.

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string userNameWithoutEncryption = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
       EncryptAppSettings("appSettings");
       string userNameWithEncrytionApplied = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
   }



   private static void EncryptAppSettings(string section)
   {
       Configuration objConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetAppPath() + "AppKeyEncryption.exe");
       AppSettingsSection objAppsettings = (AppSettingsSection)objConfig.GetSection(section);
       if (!objAppsettings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
       {
           objAppsettings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
           objAppsettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
           objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
       }
   }


   private static string GetAppPath()
   {
       System.Reflection.Module[] modules = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules();
       string location = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(modules[0].FullyQualifiedName);
       if ((location != "") && (location[location.Length - 1] != '\\'))
           location += '\\';
       return location;
   }
   ```

To decrypt the app.config file you need to call this method:

```
    private static void DecryptAppSettings(string section)
    {
        Configuration objConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetAppPath() + "AppKeyEncryption.exe");
        AppSettingsSection objAppsettings = (AppSettingsSection)objConfig.GetSection(section);
        if (objAppsettings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            objAppsettings.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
            objAppsettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
    }
```

In the above sections describe the way of encrypting configuration file to protect the sensitive information like password. Now what if we want to change the key value say password after sometime as our configuration file is encrypted we cannot update the password easily. No worries .NET framework provide the way to do so as given below:

```
    private static void UpdateKey(string newValue)
    {
        ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configFile.ExeConfigFilename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configPath"];
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["password"].Value = newValue;
        config.Save();
    }
```

For more information, here is where I found this solution and tested it myself: http://www.a2zmenu.com/blogs/csharp/how-to-encrypt-configuration-file.aspx.

I hope this helps you it worked for me!